# Correspondence between motives and automorphic representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, motives, l-functions, langlands-conjectures

**What I know:**

- I understand motives via its realization; in Coates' and Perrin-Riou's paper *On $p$-adic L-functions Attached to Motives over $\mathbb{Q}$* (see http://doi.org/10.2969/aspm/01710023), the authors define a motive over $\mathbb{Q}$ (with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$) via its realization (chapter 2).
- There is an extension of these motive realizations to number fields: more specifically, to a motive $\mathcal{M}$ over a number field $E/\mathbb{Q}$ with coefficients in some other number field $k/\mathbb{Q}$; this is explained by Panchiskin in https://archive.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/id/eprint/3120/1/preprint_1990_43.pdf .
- Clozel states in Conjecture 4.5 of https://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/AA1988a.pdf that one should be able to attach to an automorphic representation $\pi$ over $k$ a motive $\mathcal{M}_{\pi}$, such that for every finite place $\nu$ of $k$,
  $$
  L_{\nu}(\pi, s) = L_{\nu}(\mathcal{M}_{\pi}, s + c)
  $$
  for some shift $c$. But as far as I read it, one wants this correspondence to be as natural as possible; for instance for example, one wants that
  $$
  L_{\nu}(\pi \times \pi', s) = L_{\nu}(\mathcal{M}_{\pi} \otimes \mathcal{M}_{\pi'}, s + c)
  $$
  and probably some other properties as well. I guess this conjectural correspondence does not come out of nowhere, but the correspondence other way round $\mathcal{M} \mapsto \pi_{\mathcal{M}}$ should be known.

**Question:**
How does one attach to a motive $\mathcal{M}$ an automorphic representation $\pi_{\mathcal{M}}$ 'with the desired properties'? Or is there some restriction on motives (like those stated in Coates' paper) where the attachment works smoothly?

**My approach:** What I can imagine is that if $\mathcal{M}$ is such a motive, then the Euler factor at $\nu$ is defined as
$$
L_{\nu}(\mathcal{M},s) := \det(1 - X \cdot (\varphi_{\nu})_{\left|H_{\ell}(M)^{I_{\nu}}\right.})^{-1},
$$
where

- $X := q^{-s}$, $q$ being the order of the residue field of $k_{\nu}$,
- $\ell \neq \nu$ is any finite prime place different from $\nu$,
- $\varphi_{\nu}$ is the (geometric) Frobenius modulo the (absolute) inertia group $I_{\nu}$.

Then, if this characteristic polynomial decomposes over $\mathbb{C}$ (or some number field) with zeroes $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$, and one assumes nice properties on these $\alpha_i$'s (for instance that the 'corresponding principal series rep' is *unramified* and *irreducible*), then one can define $\pi := \bigotimes_{\nu}' \pi_{\nu}$, where $\pi_{\nu}$ (at least for $\nu$ finite) is the unramified principal series representation $I(\chi) := \mathrm{Ind}^{\mathrm{GL}_{n}(k_{\nu})}_{B_{n}(k_{\nu})}(\chi)$ with $\chi(\omega^{r_1}, \ldots \omega^{r_n}) = \alpha^{r_1}_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot \alpha^{r_n}_n$, $\omega$ being a uniformizer in $k_{\nu}$. Then one should have
$$
L_{\nu}(\pi_{\nu},s) = \frac{1}{(1 - \alpha_1 q^{-s})\cdot \ldots \cdot (1 - \alpha_n q^{-s})} = L_{\nu}(\mathcal{M},s).
$$
Is this attachment correct? This should also well-behave with respect to tensor products and direct sums (maybe even with respect to taking duals). Or better: Is there some paper where this attachment is discussed in detail?

Comment: Look at Taylor's ICM article.

Comment: As was told to me by Jie Lin, the correspondence is in *both* directions conjectural (not only in one as I previously assumed), and there exist only realizations in special cases. The usual direction one goes is from the automorphic to the motivic. Therefore I won't find any 'attachment', although there are some rules as what information from a cusp.rep. should correspond to what information of a motive.